# How to use List in another function

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

--------------------------------------Table 1--------------------------------------

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student_details")
public class StudentDetails {
    
    @Id
    private Long studentId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String fatherName;
    
    // with getter and setters
    
}
```

-------------------------------------Table 2---------------------------------

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student_marks")
public class StudentMarks {
    
    @Id
    private Long studentId;
    private int Maths;
    private int English;
    private int Computer;
    
    // with getter and setters
    
}
```

------------------------------------class which combine these two table------------------

```
public class StudentReportData {

    @Id
    private Long studentId;
    private String studentName
    private String fatherName;
    private int Maths;
    private int English;
    private int Computer;
    
    //with getter and setters
    
}
```

-----------------------------------Service Class---------------------------

```
@Service
public class StudentService {

    public ApiResponce<List<StudentReportData>> getStudentData() {
    
        ApiResponce<List<StudentReportData>> responce = new ApiResponce();
        Status status = new Status();
        status setSuccess(true);
        try {
            List<StudentReportData> studentList = new ArrayList<StudentReportData>();
            List<StudentMarks> findAll = studentMarksRepository.findAll();
            for(StudentMarks sm : findAll) {
                StudentReportData studentData = new StudentReportData();
                BeanUtils.copyProperties(sm, studentData);
                StudentDetails studentDetailsData = studentDetailsRepository.findByStudentId(sm.getStudentId());
                studentData.setStudentName(studentDetailsData.getFirstName()+" "+studentDetailsData.getLastName());
                studentList.add(studentData);
            }
            response.setData(studentList);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            ErrorData errorData = new ErrorData();
            errorData.setErrorCode("ERR003");
            errorData.setErrorMessage("Internal Server Error");
            status.setErrorData(errorData);
            status.setSuccess(false);
        }
        response.setStatus(status);
        return response;
    
    }
    
    
    public ByteArrayInputStream load() {
        
    
        ByteArrayInputStream in = ExcelHelper.studentreportToExcel(studentList);
        return in;
      }
    
    
}
```

I want to pass this studentList as an argument to the function `studentReportToExcel` from the function `load`. How can I get that List Inside the `load` function.

Comment: I'd better pass list as an arg in load method. Using list as a field of service class is not a good idea IMO. If you add it as arg you can call it as `service.load(service.getStudentData())`. Or you should call method right in `load` method `ByteArrayInputStream in = ExcelHelper.studentreportToExcel(getStudentData());`

Answer (score 0):

Add it as a class attribute, something like:

```
@Service
public class StudentService {
    private List<StudentReportData> studentList; // class attribute to add

    public ApiResponce<List<StudentReportData>> getStudentData() {
    
        ApiResponce<List<StudentReportData>> responce = new ApiResponce();
        Status status = new Status();
        status setSuccess(true);
        try {
            studentList = new ArrayList<StudentReportData>();  // line changed
            List<StudentMarks> findAll = studentMarksRepository.findAll();
            for(StudentMarks sm : findAll) {
                StudentReportData studentData = new StudentReportData();
                BeanUtils.copyProperties(sm, studentData);
                StudentDetails studentDetailsData = studentDetailsRepository.findByStudentId(sm.getStudentId());
                studentData.setStudentName(studentDetailsData.getFirstName()+" "+studentDetailsData.getLastName());
                studentList.add(studentData);
            }
            response.setData(studentList);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            ErrorData errorData = new ErrorData();
            errorData.setErrorCode("ERR003");
            errorData.setErrorMessage("Internal Server Error");
            status.setErrorData(errorData);
            status.setSuccess(false);
        }
        response.setStatus(status);
        return response;
    
    }
    
    
    public ByteArrayInputStream load() {
        
    
        ByteArrayInputStream in = ExcelHelper.studentreportToExcel(studentList);
        return in;
      }
    
    
}
```